# Zipalign cannot working while using 'gradlew packageRelease'

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio,But zipalign it's not working for me while I package App via 'gradlew packageRelease'.I've verify the signature is ok by jarsigner.Here is my build.gradle.It's there any mistake?

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    signingConfigs {
        myConfig{
            storeFile file("my.keystore")
            storePassword "password"
            keyAlias "alias"
            keyPassword "password"
        }
    }

    buildTypes{
        release {
            signingConfig  signingConfigs.myConfig
            runProguard true
            proguardFile "proguard.cfg"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that *Android Studio* hasn't removed the ZipAlign file from the `tools` folder - it does "helpful" things like that when you change build versions (and got me when I upgraded then had to downgrade). If it has, you may be able to find it in an older version on your file-system.

Comment: My zipalign was in `build-tools` folder. I just copied it from there and pasted in the `tools` folder and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

zipalign is in `ADT/sdk/build-tools/android4.4W` Copy `android4.4W` folder and paste it in `yourproject/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk`
Now, copy yourkey.keystore and your project.apk and paste them into `android4.4W` full path `yourproject/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android4.4W`
then, `$ zipalign -v 4 project.apk wowdone.apk`. Thats all, hope this answer will help you.